# Burninate [vstest]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

[vstest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vstest) looks like a good candidate for burninating:

- wiki references a "vtest" technology for testing web apps, but none of the questions are about this.
- All 5 questions refer to Microsoft's unit test framework, which already has the tag [mstest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mstest).

I can't imagine somebody who is an expert in the "vtest" technology subscribing to [vstest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vstest), and would be better off creating a vtest tag themselves.

I propose it be burned and existing questions migrated to [mstest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mstest)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was all ready to agree with you then I checked the questions... and [VSTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx) appears to be the replacement for MSTest (which is deprecated), and four of the questions directly refer to it (i.e. they are not mistagged, the remaining question will likely be auto culled during a monthly system clean up job).

So at this stage I would suggest you don't touch it. You could always suggest an update for the wiki though.

Comment: Ah I see, I did not know they had renamed it. Perhaps an update to the [mstest] tag wiki pointing towards [vstest] for up to date questions would be wise, too.

Comment: You don't need to point one tag to the other. Just use the tag that describes the technology you're using.

Comment: That'd be great, if that's what everybody was doing. But they're not. There are only 5 questions using vstest. Instead they are incorrectly using mstest, when the technology they're using is vstest.